# Can I use this voltmeter / ammeter without the shunt supplied along with it?

Tags: rectifier, shunt, voltmeter

I bought [this voltmeter online.](https://smarteshop.pk/product/100a-digital-display-voltmeter-ammeter-zfx-vc288-dual-led-voltage-current-tester-monitor-panel-gauge-with-shunt/)

It does not show current.

Do I need to use 10 A load for some reading or it will work for lower amps also like 1 to 2 A?

From the product details:

> Measure Current: 100A forward current (more than 10A need shunt)

What does it mean?

How I can lower lower shunt or meter current to measure lower  current rather then 10 A to start with?

I am going to this volt meter in a rectifier used in electro-plating where the current matters.

Comment: The link you show states 'ammeter" so why do you think it does not show amps? Do you understand the difference between volts and amps? and how your meter measures both?

Comment: the title of your post has errors

Comment: Please post a schematic of your connections and/or a picture of your setup.

Answer (score 2):

You have the 100A shunt.  It should read 1.0A at 1A.

Comment: will it reads 0.1amp if i use 0.1 amp motor using shunt??This is written in the  product details  Measure Current: 100A forward current ( more than 10A need shunt)      

What does it means?????

Comment: @NaveedAA Reading the rest of the page, I _think_ the phrase "100A forward current (more than 10A need shunt)" means "This is a meter which reads up to 100A. All the meters in our range rated over 10A [that is: including this one] need to use a shunt". Especially because on the same page is "The meter with a range 100A must be connected to the shunt to measure the current no matter whether the measured current is less than 10A! " The page is not written in clear English. There is a diagram showing how to wire the shunt on the page at the bottom: use that and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

> I bought online this voltmeter

You have purchased an item with no datasheet available. That's generally a bad start as we have no way of knowing what's inside. The cartoons on the website are inadequate.

> it does not show amps

It does. There is an **A** symbol on the display.

> do i need to use 10amps load for some reading or it will work in lower amps also like 1 to 2 amps

It will display 0 to 100 A with the shunt provided.

> how i can lower lower shunt or meter amps to measure lower amp rather then 10amps to start with

To do this you would need to purchase the correct shunt for the range of current you are interested in and with the correct output voltage for your meter.

> As i am going to this volt meter in rectifier used in electro plating which sensitive with current matter

"Current matter"?

---

Tip: please punctuate and capitalise your sentences properly for ease of reading and understanding.

Comment: Given the website the OP provided, and their profile name, it's likely that they are not a native English speaker.  So I'd cut them some slack in that area

Answer (score 1):

It should read roughly correctly, however if you are always going to to use it at < 10A it would be much better (more accurate) to buy a similar instrument that reads 10A full scale.

Accuracy is specified as +/-1%. That means that if it reads (say) 2A, the actual current could be anywhere between 1A and 3A and the meter would be within specifications. There's probably an additional error associated with the shunt, but that's likely not very important at small currents.

Comment: Measure Current: 100A forward current ( more than 10A need shunt)?????

Comment: The information given covers multiple models, ones with 10A or less full-scale range do not require an external shunt (the shunt is built-in).

Comment: my meter is of 100anps so what this comment means in product details

"Measure Current: 100A forward current ( more than 10A need shunt)"

Comment: Does it mean my shunt should be not less then 10 amps

Comment: The part about 10A does not apply to the product you purchased.

Comment: I understand that u mean that comment is for the product that does not include external shunt. If my amp meter does not showing amps it means faulty if correction r 100% correct

Comment: @NaveedAA There are many reasons your meter might not show current. Wrong wiring, or current too low to display come to mind.